# Umbraco ContourContrib Error

Tags: dll, umbraco, captcha, recaptcha, umbraco-contour

So I have a bunch of forms that I made using Umbraco contour and I'm also using the ReCaptcha datatype contained in the ContourContrib package.

My problem is that after reinstalling ContourContrib, I now get server errors saying:

**Error adding macro Insert form from Umbraco Contour
Method 'Contour.Contrib.FieldTypes.ReCaptcha.ToolTip' not found.**

I looked in the Contour.Contrib.dll and indeed there is no method called "Tooltip" in the referenced namespace and class.  The oddest part is that after looking through Codeplex, I can't even find where that method ever even existed.

So my next thought was to remove the field in Contour and add it again.  That might work, but I can't even get the "Forms" section of Contour to expand anymore because of this error.

I'm really at a loss and I'm hoping that smarter people than myself have some clue as to a different avenue I can take to resolve this.

Thanks for you time,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I was reinstalling a version that was 2 versions ahead of where I was before.  I was installing v0.0.5 but the Contour.Contrib.dll only contained a method called tooltip in v0.0.2 and prior.  Beware of this if you already have forms made and are thinking about upgrading.